# Can my use case be merged into a single query without affecting performance?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

Am mainly looking at improving the *performance* of the query and also whether be able to solve in a *single query* for one of my use case explained below:

There are 2 tables involved:

```
Table 1: EMPLOYEE (column1, column2, email1, email2, column5, column6)
Table 2: EMAILLIST (email)
```

My requirement is, I want to get/fetch all records from the table EMPLOYEE with the condition that either email1 or email2 do not have a matching entry in EMAILLIST table. To put it simply, if either email1 or email2 matches in EMAILLIST table, then those records should be ignored.

In this case, EMPLOYEE.EMAIL1, EMPLOYEE.EMAIL2 and EMAILLIST.EMAIL will *always* have single email address stored.

We're using PostgreSQL v8.2.3, if it matters.

Any pointers/ideas/logic are appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Currently, we've implemented in this way: Fetched all records from EMPLOYEE table and stored in a Java object and for each entry (for loop), this in turn checks in EMAILLIST table, which is costly in terms of performance.

Comment: Offtopic: PostgreSQL v8.2.3 is already 4 years old and 16 patch rounds behind. Consider maintenance before you get into serious trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to handle this for every rdbms I've dealt with is to handle it with outer joins:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM employee AS e
LEFT JOIN emaillist AS em1 ON e.email1 = em1.email
LEFT JOIN emaillist AS em2 ON e.email2 = em2.email
WHERE em1.id IS NULL
    AND em2.id IS NULL
```

In general, I think you'll find that any case where you put database queries into a loop will be, ummm, suboptimal. :)

Comment: From the OP's description "if either ... matches in emaillist then those records should be ignored", I think you want an AND in your WHERE clause, not an OR.

Comment: I changed it - the problem statement is a bit confused. Anyway, if it's not AND, it's probably OR. :)

Comment: @le dorfier: What is `em1.id` and `em2.id` in your query?

Comment: It's any field that would be populated (not null) from the outer-joined tables. That's how you know you didn't have a match. Generally "id" would be the primary key for the table.

Comment: @le dorfier: In this case, we don't have any primary key maintained in EMAILLIST table.  It is just a flat table only with email address stored.  In that case, can I instead have like this `em1.email IS NULL and em2.email IS NULL`?

Comment: @Gnanam testing em1.email and em2.email for null as you proposed will work fine

Comment: @le dorfier: I tried this query and it is working fine.  Can you explain on how this query is really working?  Particularly, I don't understand `em1.id IS NULL AND em2.id IS NULL` in WHERE condition.

Comment: The outer joins try to match two different records in the emaillist table. Unlike inner joins, an outer join will return the row from the primary table (employee) even if no match is found. If a match were made to a record in em1, then em1.email would return the email field value (which you happened to be joining on, but that's inconsequential). If there is no match for the join then any field in emaillist will be null (because there is no record.) So to test for "no record found", test whether an otherwise un-NULLable field is NULL.

Comment: @le dorfier: Thanks for making me understand. By the way, is not the first query using LEFT JOIN given by @Conrad's similar to your solution?

Comment: Logically they are all equivalent. The question is how query optimizers decompose and execute SQL expressions. If he had made two outer joins it would be equivalent. Query optimizers generally don't reconstruct OR expressions wherever they determine index choice

Comment: @le dorfier: Again thanks for your comments. I couldn't completely understand from this -- `Query optimizers generally don't reconstruct OR expressions wherever they determine index choice`.  What will happen/be the implication if OR expressions are *not* reconstructed?  Will there be any difference in performance of the query when the table grows in size? Or something else?

Comment: The most efficient joins are joins on two fields. That's why my query has two of this type of join. Less efficient is when a join involves an expression which is what happens in the LEFT JOIN example from Contrad - for each record it will try (and fail) for a match and then it will be able to evaluate the WHERE clause.

There's a lot of SQL that you learn just by running into it a few times yourself. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to handle this

### LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM employee AS e
LEFT JOIN emaillist AS em 
ON e.email1 = em.email
   or e.Email2 = em.email
 WHERE
     em.email is null
```

### NOT EXISTs

```
SELECT *
FROM employee AS e
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM  
                 emaillist AS em 
              WHERE e.email1 = em.email
                  or e.email2 = em.Email)
```

### NOT IN

```
SELECT *
FROM employee AS e
WHERE
    e.email1 NOT IN (SELECT email
               FROM  
                 emaillist)
    and
     e.email2 NOT IN (SELECT email
               FROM  
                 emaillist)
```

Comment: These are less efficient. #1 uses OR in the WHERE clause and the other two have correlated subqueries (something to avoid.)

Comment: @le dorfier. Check again.  The first one uses  an OR in the FROM clause. Not sure about the supposed inefficiencies. It can vary a lot depending on the data and backend. Its better to test then to suppose what's faster

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see which one works best. NOT IN() might be a problem, don't use this one when you have many values.

Comment: Is not your first query based on `LEFT JOIN` is something similar to @le dorfier's solution?

Comment: NOT IN and possibly even NOT EXISTS may be a problem on PostgreSQL 8.2 - they are both handled better in more modern version. LEFT JOIN is likely the fastest one in this version - but as Frank suggests, use EXPLAIN to find out which gives you the best plan.