# How to query if either EMPLOYEE.EMAIL1 or EMPLOYEE.EMAIL2 do not have a matching entry?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

In continuation to a question posted by me on 
[Can my use case explained be solved in a single query without affecting performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4612710/181870), I've a different requirement now and I wonder whether this could be again solved in a single query without affecting performance.  My new requirement explained below:

There are 2 tables involved:

```
Table 1: EMPLOYEE (column1, column2, email1, email2, column5, column6)
Table 2: EMAILLIST (email)
```

My new requirement is, if *both* EMPLOYEE.EMAIL1 and EMPLOYEE.EMAIL2 have a matching entry in EMAILLIST table, then this row should be ignored. Hence, if either EMPLOYEE.EMAIL1 or EMPLOYEE.EMAIL2 do not have a matching entry (which means atleast one of the column will have a matching entry), I expect this row should be returned.  Because either one of the email do not have a matching entry, I need a identification in SELECT clause itself on which email (email1 or email2) did not have a matching entry in EMAILLIST table.

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO EMAILLIST (email) VALUES ('test1@domain.com');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (column1, column2, email1, email2, column5, column6) VALUES ('c1', 'c2', 'test1@domain.com', 'test2@domain.com', 'c5', 'c6');
```

I expect to return with some identification in query output on which one of the email do not have a matching entry like this:

```
EMAIL1           | EMAIL2            | EMAIL1MATCHED | EMAIL2MATCHED
test1@domain.com | test2@domain.com  | Yes           | No
```

We're using PostgreSQL v8.2.3, if it matters.

**UPDATE:** My table size are little huge: EMPLOYEE has got 165018 records and EMAILLIST has got 1810228 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the `email` column of `emaillist` is indexed, this should be fine:

```
 SELECT employee.email1, employee.email2,
        e1.email IS NOT NULL AS email1_matched, e2.email IS NOT NULL AS email2_matched
   FROM employee
   LEFT JOIN emaillist e1 ON e1.email = employee.email1
   LEFT JOIN emaillist e2 ON e2.email = employee.email2
 WHERE e1.email IS NULL OR e2.email IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  email1, email2,
                email1 IN
                (
                SELECT  email
                FROM    emaillist
                ) AS email1matched,
                email2 IN
                (
                SELECT  email
                FROM    emaillist
                ) AS email2matched
        FROM    employee
        ) q
WHERE   email1matched <> email2matched
```

Comment: Am getting `ERROR: write failed SQL state: XX000` while running this query.  My table size are little huge: EMPLOYEE has got 165018 records and EMAILLIST has got 1810228 records.

Comment: Sorry, the above error was because of *out of disk space*.  But then this query is taking too long to complete.

Comment: You query has subqueries, apparently that's the problem according to https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw/issues/39

Comment: @DIEGOF.G. don't use them then with this driver.

Comment: @Quassnoi I know I had to create a temp table using all the data from that query, then use my where clause in my database, ogr doesn't work that well when you use where clauses